# Returning Values from a autocad command to windows form application

Tags: c#, autocad

I have created AutoCAD plugins to measure a distance of line .Alongside i have created a windows form application that load the plugins i have created. I try to return the value measured using command in my AutoCAD plugins to the windows form application but all went in vain.Some of the way i do are:

> I insert the result obtained in autocad and try to retrive that.
>   I try the interface technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your distance in the [USERR1 to USERR5](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-4e0e.htm,topicNumber=d0e359177) system variables, then read it with `Document.GetVariable` COM API from an external process.

You can install an handler on the `EndCommand` event to detect when your command is finished.

Here is some code:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop;

[..]

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const uint MK_E_UNAVAILABLE = 0x800401e3;

    AcadApplication acad;
    try
    {
        // Try to get a running instance of AutoCAD 2016
        acad = (AcadApplication) Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.20.1");
    }
    catch (COMException ex) when ((uint) ex.ErrorCode == MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)
    {
        // AutoCAD is not running, we start it
        acad = (AcadApplication) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoCAD.Application.20.1"));
    }
    activeDocument = acad.ActiveDocument;
    activeDocument.EndCommand += ActiveDocument_EndCommand;
    activeDocument.SendCommand("YOURCOMMAND ");
}

void ActiveDocument_EndCommand(string CommandName)
{
    if (CommandName != "YOURCOMMAND") return;
    try
    {
        double value = activeDocument.GetVariable("USERR1");
        // Process the value
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        // Remove the handler
        activeDocument.EndCommand -= ActiveDocument_EndCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading your plugin in AutoCAD from your windows form application ? And how are you launching the command?

Comment: You just need to add: (command " + (char)34 + "NETLOAD" + (char)34 + " " +
                                                (char)34 +(Your Dll Path) + (char)34 + ")"; at the button click event.To lauch command just used SendCommand

Comment: I am new on this.So being dumb i am asking how to install an handler on the EndCommand event.It would be great if you could provide me with example.